# In Hive, How to select only values of one of the dynamic partitions (when there are one or more partitions available)

Tags: hive, hiveql

Now I have a table which has a structure as follows,

```
hive> desc clicks_fact;
    OK
    time                    timestamp                                   
    ..                              
    day                     date                                        
    file_date               varchar(8)                                  

    # Partition Information      
    # col_name              data_type               comment             

    day                     date                                        
    file_date               varchar(8)                                  
    Time taken: 1.075 seconds, Fetched: 28 row(s)
```

Now I want to get partitions of this table.

```
hive> show partitions clicks_fact;
OK
day=2016-09-02/file_date=20160902
..
day=2017-06-30/file_date=20170629
Time taken: 0.144 seconds, Fetched: 27 row(s)
```

I could get the partitions as combination of both `day & file_date`. 
Now, Is there any way to get only the values of `file_date`

Comment: "dynamic partitions" is a concept that relates to INSERT operation and is not relevant to your post

Comment: Why do you define `file_date` as string/int and not as date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive offers very limited options for metadata retrieval.
Query the metastore directly.

#### demo

**Hive**

```
create table clicks_fact (i int) partitioned by (day date,file_date int)
;

alter table clicks_fact add
    partition (day=date '2016-09-02',file_date=20160901)
    partition (day=date '2016-09-02',file_date=20160902)
    partition (day=date '2016-09-03',file_date=20160901)
    partition (day=date '2016-09-03',file_date=20160902)
    partition (day=date '2016-09-03',file_date=20160903)
;
```

**Metastore (MySQL)**

```
use metastore;


select  distinct
        pkv.PART_KEY_VAL
        
from            DBS                 as d

        join    TBLS                as t
        
        on      t.DB_ID =
                d.DB_ID

        join    PARTITION_KEYS      as pk
        
        on      pk.TBL_ID =
                t.TBL_ID

        join    PARTITIONS          as p
        
        on      p.TBL_ID =
                t.TBL_ID       

        join    PARTITION_KEY_VALS  as pkv
        
        on      pkv.PART_ID =
                p.PART_ID
                
            and pkv.INTEGER_IDX =
                pk.INTEGER_IDX       

where   d.NAME       = 'local_db'
    and t.TBL_NAME   = 'clicks_fact'
    and pk.PKEY_NAME = 'file_date'
;
```

---

```
+--------------+
| PART_KEY_VAL |
+--------------+
|     20160901 |
|     20160902 |
|     20160903 |
+--------------+
```